# Internet Explorer inline border bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a list and each list element is inline. I add border to the li a elements, but every row except the first row, it cut out the border and padding. It works in every browser, except Internet explorer 7. Do you have any solution?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/88ca5acd54.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/88ca5acd54.jpg)

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 12</li>
    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 5</li>

    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 4</li>
    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 3</li>
    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 2</li>
    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 2</li>

    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 1</li>
    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 1</li>
    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 1</li>
    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 1</li>

    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 1</li>
    <li>
        <a class="temakor" href="*" >??</a>&nbsp;x 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .container{
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    li{
        display: inline;
        line-height:30px;
    }

    li{
        color: #35a9e5;
        font-weight:bold;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
        .temakor{
            color:#a2a2a2;
            background-color:#3B3B3B;
            border:2px solid #678194;
            padding:3px 10px;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding will not work the same on an inline element as it does on a block element.

Comment: to do what you want display the li as block and float them left.

Answer (score 0):

try add style for li

```
zoom:1; *display:inline;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solved the same issue for me:

```
position:relative;
```